# I can't run my app (android studio)

Tags: java, android, xml, nullpointerexception

There is the eror message on the monitor:

```
07-20 17:00:05.234 17194-17194/com.example.champion.courtcounter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.champion.courtcounter/com.example.champion.courtcounter.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #69: Error inflating class null
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2129)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2154)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:146)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1260)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4949)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1043)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #69: Error inflating class null
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                   at com.example.champion.courtcounter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5185)
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2154) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:146) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1260) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4949) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1043) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810) 
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:101)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1029)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1087)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:681)
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                   at com.example.champion.courtcounter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16) 
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5185) 
                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2154) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:146) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1260) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4949) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1043) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810) 
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

There is my xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="Team A"
            android:textColor="#616161"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="24dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="56sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:onClick="points3"
            android:text="+3 points" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:onClick="points2"
            android:text="+2 points" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:onClick="point"
            android:text="free throw" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <view
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="Team B"
            android:textColor="#616161"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_b_score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="24dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="56sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:onClick="points3B"
            android:text="+3 points" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:onClick="points2B"
            android:text="+2 points" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:onClick="pointB"
            android:text="free throw" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:onClick="reset"
    android:text="reset" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

There is my java code:

```
package com.example.champion.courtcounter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.champion.courtcounter.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int numA=0;
int numB=0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void displayForTeamA(int score) {
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_score);
    scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}

public void points3(View view) {
    numA = numA + 3;
    displayForTeamA(numA);
}
public void points2(View view) {
    numA = numA + 2;
    displayForTeamA(numA);
}
public void point(View view) {
    numA = numA + 1;
    displayForTeamA(numA);
}

public void displayForTeamB(int score) {
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_b_score);
    scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}
public void points3B(View view) {
    numB = numB + 3;
    displayForTeamB(numB);
}
public void points2B(View view) {
    numB = numB + 2;
    displayForTeamB(numB);
}
public void pointB(View view) {
    numB = numB + 1;
    displayForTeamB(numB);
}
public void reset(View view) {
    numB = 0;
    displayForTeamB(numB);
    numA = 0;
    displayForTeamA(numA);
 }
}
```

I can't even open it. When I try to open it's says:"Unfortunately, Court Counter(the name of my app) has stopped.
Thank for help.

Comment: Please show your manifest file. May be the reason is in wrong activity theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<view
   android:layout_width="1dp"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
   android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
```

Change `view` with `View`

Comment: Wow I don't belive that all. Thank you very mich!!!! :)

Comment: I can do it only one minute more... I will do.